# Is the pre-image of a compact space compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm trying to think of an example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(X)$ is not compact but $ X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact. Any ideas?

Comment: $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, $X=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. More generally, *any* bounded function will work: if $-M\leq f(x)\leq M$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f^{-1}([-M,M])=\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map

Comment: @Arturo: this suggests, if I haven't missed something, that a continuous , bounded map:f:X-->Y ; Y metric, with f(X) closed, cannot have a continuous inverse (since continuous image takes compact to compact).

Comment: @AQP: Depends on what you mean by inverse. If you mean, a map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that is a two-sided inverse, you already knew that because a bounded map cannot be onto.

Comment: @Arturo. Right, I missed that obvious point.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What about the the constant function $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $X$ is compact, it is closed, and so $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed.  Now take your favourite set that is closed but not compact, call that $B$, and let $f(x) = \text{dist}(x,B)$.  That is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$, and $B = f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the continuous function $\sin x$